# Package conflicting for basemap and cartopy

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, matplotlib-basemap, cartopy

I have already installed the basemap package. It worked well in my Python 2.7 environment in the Anaconda jupyter environment.

I want to install `cartopy` and learn this package for geospatial data mapping.

```
conda install -c conda-forge gdal geos pyproj shapely cartopy
```

the package seemed to be successfully installed.

However, when I want to import this package, the error showed like:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
dlopen(/Users/HYF/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cartopy/trace.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libgeos_c.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/HYF/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cartopy/trace.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: trace.so requires version 12.0.0 or later, but libgeos_c.dylib provides version 11.0.0
```

I read some website where some one also met with this problem and ask for help. The error should be related to the conflicting between different package dependencies.

Therefore, I re-installed the Basemap package in the  `conda` channel by:

```
conda install -c conda-forge basemap
```

Then, the `basemap` package and `cartopy` package are both failed to import.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
dlopen(/Users/HYF/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_geoslib.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libgeos_c.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/HYF/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_geoslib.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: _geoslib.so requires version 12.0.0 or later, but libgeos_c.dylib provides version 11.0.0
```

I have also tried `conda install -c conda-forge basemap cartopy` refering to [link](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/771), but the problem was still there.

It seems that basmap package was against to the older geos library (version 3.3.x), while the cartopy was based on geos 3.4.x.

### PS

Sorry for unclear interpretation, I want to fix the problem that **installing Basemap and cartopy without any error**

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I faced similar difficulties as yours but later overcame it, but already forget how I did. But the situation prompted me to create new python environment for using cartopy.

Comment: I have already fixed this problem and updated my question with my solution.

Comment: Instead of adding the answer to your question, could you please post the solution as an answer (answer your own question) and accept it? This way others will know that this question needs no further attention.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this problem by following the order as follows:

```
## Uninstall cartopy and shapely, keep the basemap
conda uninstall cartopy    
conda uninstall shapely

## upgrade the gdal using brew method 
brew upgrade gdal

## install shapely cartopy using pip
pip install shapely cartopy --no-binary shapely --no-binary cartopy

## reinstall shapely using conda
conda install shapely
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by reinstalling libgdal:

```
conda install libdgal
```